# SQL recursive get BOM from PSP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, recursive-query, autodesk, byte-order-mark

I am having a MS SQL Server (2016) and a database which contains i.a. table like this : (it´s a view created in an Autodesk PSP Database - please don´t ask why ... :-) )

| CHILD_AIMKEY | QUANTITY | PARENT_AIMKEY | StatusOfParent | StatusOfChild |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5706657 | 1 | 5664344 | 100 | 103 |
| 5706745 | 1 | 5664344 | 100 | 103 |
| 5707104 | 1 | 5664344 | 100 | 103 |
| 5707109 | 1 | 5664344 | 100 | 100 |
| 5801062 | 1 | 5664344 | 100 | 103 |

The "children" can contain other "children" and in that case they would be their "parents".

So it´s a standard structured BOM table from a CAD PDM System.

If I do the following "Select Statement" I get all the children of the top level parent:

```
SELECT [CHILD_AIMKEY] , [POSITION], [QUANTITY] ,[PARENT_AIMKEY],[StatusOfParent],[StatusChild] FROM database_table where Parent_aimkey = '5664344'
```

(as shown in the table above)

My first question is : How to recursivly process all children of each parent from that table ? (Could be an other table or direct output)
The format should be: Parent_Aimkey, Child_Aimkey, Quantity

The second question is a bit more complicated:

I try it with some "pseudo code":

```
If Tree_Level_of_DIRECT_Parent < 3 then show CHILD_AIMKEY,QUANTITY in queryresult_above
If Tree_Level_of_DIRECT_Parent > 2 and StatusOf_DIRECT_Parent = 103 and StatusOf_DIRECT_Child = 103 then show CHILD_AIMKEY,QUANTITY in queryresult_above
```

Is that in some way possible ? (If there is a need to extend the database view of an other field or another table, that´s no problem)

I know this looks a bit confusing, but what I need is the Autodesk Inventor structured BOM in an SQL Statement or stored procedure.

Any would be really much appreciated

Thanks

Alex.

Comment: *"How to recursivly process all children of each parent from that table"* With an recursuve Common Table Expression (rCTE).

Comment: For the second part, use `CASE` expressions? It's unclear as you seem to want multiple differing columns and you don't also provide expected results/

Comment: For the second part : to be clear : if < 3 is true ... and the same for if > 2 is true

Comment: @Larnu Yes i know that could do the job, but i am not used to use CTE´s, never did that before...